# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway error after installing tomcat 8

Tags: php, linux, tomcat, nginx, fedora

I am getting bad gateway error After installing tomcat8.
I dont know what may be the problem to check problem I used `nginx -t` this is not shoing any error
I have 3 config file which I have posted here

I run

```
#nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

nginx.conf

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
# #
     server {
        listen       80 default_server;
         listen       [::]:80 default_server;
         server_name  _;
         root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

         # Load configuration files for the default server block.
         include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

         location / {
         }
     ## Add the following lines ##

    location ~ \.php$ {
              root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
              try_files $uri =404;
              fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
              fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
              fastcgi_index  index.php;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              include        fastcgi_params;
      }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

conf.d/tomcat.conf
 cat tomcat.conf

```
server {
  listen          80;
  server_name     45.55.62.37;

 # proxy_cache one;

  location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  }
}
```

conf.d/php-frm.conf

```
cat php-fpm.conf
# PHP-FPM FastCGI server
# network or unix domain socket configuration

upstream php-fpm {
        server unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
```

What may be the problemand how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Please check that your tomcat is running correctly on your server.

Try this cmd and check if port 8080 is listening on 127.0.0.1:8080 :

netstat -ntplu

I think the problem is not on nginx but on tomcat check the logs.

Comment: Yes It is Showing  `tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      20755/java
`

Comment: http://45.55.62.37:8080/ is showing tomcat but http://45.55.62.37/ ig giving  502 Bad Gateway

Comment: in your conf.d/tomcat.conf, change proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/; to proxy_pass http://45.55.62.37:8080/; check if that works.